# как правильно нарезать список списков на "СТРОКИ" и "СТОЛБЦЫ"?

Tags: python, массивы, list

```
m = [[7, 2, 7],
     [2, 9, 4],
     [6, 6, 5]]

row = m[0][:]
print(row)
col = m[:][0]
print(col)
```

на выходе  две одинаковых строки:

```
[7, 2, 7]
[7, 2, 7]
```

Заглянув в http://pythontutor.com/ обнаружил удивительное:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вместо ожидаемого столбца в `col = m[:][0]` имею копию первой строки.
Два вопроса:
 - почему так?
 - как получить столбец?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360162/how-to-access-a-column-in-a-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае удобно пользоваться "родным" индексированием Numpy:

Исходный массив:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[7, 2, 7],
              [2, 9, 4],
              [6, 6, 5]])
```

Пример:

```
In [114]: a
Out[114]:
array([[7, 2, 7],
       [2, 9, 4],
       [6, 6, 5]])

In [115]: a[:,1]
Out[115]: array([2, 9, 6])
```

Хотя для таких простых случаев использование Numpy не совсем оправдано

Также можно воспользоваться [трюком с транспонированием](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip):

```
In [116]: m
Out[116]: [[7, 2, 7], [2, 9, 4], [6, 6, 5]]

In [117]: list(zip(*m))[1]
Out[117]: (2, 9, 6)

In [118]: list(zip(*m))
Out[118]: [(7, 2, 6), (2, 9, 6), (7, 4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 4):

`m[:][0]` означает скопировать полностью список `m` и взять первый элемент. Соответственно это и будет первая строка.

Получить столбец можно так:

```
col = [x[0] for x in m]
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
for row in m:
    print('row:', row)

for idx in range(len(m[0])):
    column = []
    for row in m:  
        column.append(row[idx])
    print('column:', column)
```

В 1 линию:

```
print(*('\n'.join(map(lambda row: 'row: {}'.format(row), m)), '\n'.join(map(lambda column: 'column: {}'.format(column), ([row[idx] for row in m] for idx in range(len(m[0])))))), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну конечно две одинаковые)

Почему так?

1. `m[:]` вернет Вам то же, что и в `m`
2. Берете `0` элемент из `m` - получаете строку по `0` индексу

Как получить столбец?

```
col = list(row[0] for row in m)
```